# VSIX Manifest Editor The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsixmanifest

I have a VSIX project. While trying to add a new command, or trying to add an asset to source.extension.vsixmanifest, I get the following error:

> --------------------------- Microsoft Visual Studio
> --------------------------- VSIX Manifest Editor
>
> ### The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057
> (E_INVALIDARG))
> --------------------------- OK

I tried to delete vs, bin, obj folders and clean
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

but still have this error. Also I ran Visual Studio with / Log but didn't find anything interesting.

Comment: Try to create a new project to test whether the issue persists.

Comment: Hi Romashkin, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether your VS has something wrong. Please try the following steps:

**1)** disable any third party extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**--> **Installed**

**2)** try to run [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) under **Developer Command Prompt for VS2019** to start a new pure VS to test whether the issue happens again.

**3)** delete all cache files under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx(16.0 is VS2019 while 15.0 is VS2017)\ComponentModelCache`

**4)** [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update it to the latest version

## **Update 1**

Reinstall VS and finally solve the issue.

Comment: I don't know what exactly was wrong, but even the repair didn't help and in complete despair, I manually uninstalled and installed Visual Studio, after this problem has gone.